# How do I correct my Sorter methods to allow for more user input?

Tags: java, algorithm, sorting, hashmap, java.util.scanner

I am trying to build a sorting algorithm for a few friends of mine, and I am making a test build for it right now. Eventually I will have it more dynamic, but currently I just have it to where it takes in user input for one's name and whatever number they enter. However, when I run the code, it asks for name input, but then it terminates right as it says to input a numeric value. I've been dealing with this for half an hour now and, honestly, I'm a bit stumped.

My code is as follows:

```
//Sorter.java
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Sorter {

    public static void dict() {

        // Create a dictionary
        Map<String, Range> dictionary = new HashMap<>();

        // Add groups and their corresponding value ranges
        dictionary.put("Family A", new Range(0, 10));
        dictionary.put("Family B", new Range(11, 20));
        dictionary.put("Family C", new Range(21, 30));

        // Retrieve the value range for a specific group
        Range rangea = dictionary.get("Family A");
        System.out.println("Value range for Family A: " + rangea.getStart() + " - " + rangea.getEnd());
        Range rangeb = dictionary.get("Family B");
        System.out.println("Value range for Family B: " + rangeb.getStart() + " - " + rangeb.getEnd());
        Range rangec = dictionary.get("Family C");
        System.out.println("Value range for Family C: " + rangec.getStart() + " - " + rangec.getEnd());

    }

    public static String getName() {
        try (Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in)) {
            System.out.print("Enter your name: ");
            if (scanner.hasNextLine()) {
                String nameInput = scanner.nextLine();
                System.out.println("Hello, " + nameInput + ".");
                return nameInput;
            } else {
                // handle no input available
                return null;
            }
        }
    }

/**
 * Prompts the user to enter a numerical value and prints the corresponding family group.
 */
    public static void counter() {
        try (Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in)) {
            System.out.print("Enter a numerical value: ");
            if (scanner.hasNextLine()) {
                String userInputString = scanner.nextLine();
                try {
                    int userInput = Integer.parseInt(userInputString);
                    String whatFamily = getGroup(userInput);
                    System.out.println("Family: " + whatFamily);
                } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
                    System.out.println("No Family LOL get rekt");
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
    }

    /**
     * Determines the group based on the given value.
     *
     * @param  value  the value to be evaluated
     * @return        the group corresponding to the value
     */
    public static String getGroup(int value) {
        // Check if the value is less than 0
        if (value < 0) {
            return "Family A";
        }
        // Check if the value is within the range of Family A
        else if (value >= 1 && value <= 10) {
            return "Family A";
        }
        // Check if the value is within the range of Family B
        else if (value >= 11 && value <= 20) {
            return "Family B";
        }
        // Check if the value is within the range of Family C
        else if (value >= 21 && value <= 30) {
            return "Family C";
        }
        // Check if the value is greater than 30
        else if (value > 30) {
            return "Family C";
        }
        // Value is outside the range of any family
        else {
            return "No Family LOL get rekt";
        }
    }
}

class Range {
    private int start;
    private int end;

    public Range(int start, int end) {
        this.start = start;
        this.end = end;
    }

    public int getStart() {
        return start;
    }

    public int getEnd() {
        return end;
    }
}
```

```
//Exec.java

import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

public class Exec {
    /**
     * Initializes a dictionary with groups and their corresponding value ranges.
     * Prints the value range for each group and prompts user input.
     *
     * @param  args  command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        // Prompt user input
        Sorter.getName();
        Sorter.dict();
        Sorter.counter();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your try-with-resources blocks are causing problems as try with resources closes the open `InputStream` when done (which one should not do with a Scanner for the console). Once a console Scanner is open, if you close it in the same program you won't be able to re-open it.

Try the following to see this behavior.

```
try (Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in)) {
     System.out.print("Prompting for input:");
     if (scanner.hasNextLine()) {
         String s = scanner.nextLine();
         System.out.println(s);
     }         
 }
 try (Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in)) {
     System.out.print("Prompting for input again: ");
     if (scan.hasNextLine()) {
         String s = scan.nextLine();
         System.out.println(s);
     }         
 }
```

Just use one scanner and pass it to the methods. And eliminate the try-with resources blocks.

```
// Prompt user input
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
Sorter.getName(scanner);
Sorter.dict();
Sorter.counter(scanner);
```

Answer (score 2):

> *"... when I run the code, it asks for name input, but then it terminates right as it says to input a numeric value. ..."*

This is because *scanner.hasNextLine* is returning *false* within the *counter* method.

After removing the condition, an exception will occur, from the *scanner.nextLine* call.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.util.NoSuchElementException: No line found
    at java.base/java.util.Scanner.nextLine(Scanner.java:1660)
    at Sorter.counter ...
```

This is because you're *try-with-resources* statements are closing the *static* *[System#in](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/System.html#in)* stream.

Use a single *Scanner* instance; place *scanner* as a *static* field of *Sorter*.
And, utilize this object in *getName* and *counter*.

And, instead checking *hasNextLine*, use *[String#isBlank](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/String.html#isBlank())* on *nextLine*.

```java
class Sorter {
    static Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);

    public static void dict() {...}

    public static String getName() {
        System.out.print("Enter your name: ");
        String nameInput = scanner.nextLine();
        if (!nameInput.isBlank()) {
            System.out.println("Hello, " + nameInput + ".");
            return nameInput;
        } else {
            // handle no input available
            return null;
        }
    }

    public static void counter() {
        System.out.print("Enter a numerical value: ");
        String userInputString = scanner.nextLine();
        try {
            if (userInputString.isBlank()) throw new Exception(); 
            int userInput = Integer.parseInt(userInputString);
            String whatFamily = getGroup(userInput);
            System.out.println("Family: " + whatFamily);
        } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
            System.out.println("No Family LOL get rekt");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        
    }
...
}
```

As a recommendation, *encapsulate* a *[LinkedHashMap](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/docs/api/java.base/java/util/LinkedHashMap.html)* class in order to provide functionality to the *Range* object.

```java
class RangeMap<K, V extends Range> extends LinkedHashMap<K, Range> {
    Range put(K key, int i, int n) {
        return super.put(key, new Range(i, n));
    }

    Range get(int i, int n) {
        return super.get(new Range(i, n));
    }

    AbstractMap.SimpleEntry<K, Range> find(int x) {
        Range copy;
        for (Map.Entry<K, Range> e : entrySet()) {
            copy = e.getValue();
            if (x >= copy.getStart() && x <= copy.getEnd())
                return new SimpleEntry<>(e.getKey(), e.getValue());
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

Now you can re-factor the *getGroup* method.
You'll need to increase the scope, and switch the context, of *dictionary*.

```java
class Sorter {
    static Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    // Create a dictionary
    static RangeMap<String, Range> dictionary = new RangeMap<>();
...
    public static String getGroup(int value) {
        AbstractMap.SimpleEntry<String, Range> r = dictionary.find(value);
        if (r != null) return r.getKey();
        return "No Family LOL get rekt";
    }
...
}
```

Additionally, you can modify the *dict* method.

```java
public static void dict() {
    // Add groups and their corresponding value ranges
    dictionary.put("Family A", 0, 10);
    dictionary.put("Family B", 11, 20);
    dictionary.put("Family C", 21, 30);

    // Retrieve the value range for a specific group
    Range range;
    for (Map.Entry<String, Range> e : dictionary.entrySet()) {
        range = e.getValue();
        System.out.printf("Value range for %s: %d - %d%n",
                          e.getKey(), range.start(), range.end());
    }
}
```

On a final note, you can utilize a *[record](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/language/records.html)* for the *Range* class.
This will force the names *getStart* to *start* and *getEnd* to *end*.

```java
record Range(int start, int end) { }
```